# meteor accounts-password error

Tags: node.js, meteor, bcrypt, meteor-accounts, node-gyp

I'm trying to add an login system to my app, using meteor accounts-facebook worked perfectly, but I don't know why with accounts-password seems that doesn't work. This is the message that appears.

```
**C:\Users\Desktop\simple-todos>meteor add accounts-password
 => Errors while adding packages:
While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.8.7:
error: Command failed:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
rebuild --no-bin-links --update-binary
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with
exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd
C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.temp-hbsxuh\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.temp-hbsxuh\npm-debug.log
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with
exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd
C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.temp-hbsxuh\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.temp-hbsxuh\npm-debug.log**
```

Can someone explain me why with facebook works and not with account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, looks like you're using the newest version of meteor without installing the `MS Build Tools`.

Accounts-password requires something called the `npm-bcrypt` which it uses for password hashing.

Now to install `npm-bcrypt` you need a native addon build tool which in turn needs the `MS Build Tools` ([which you can download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)). So just install it and you're good. [Read more here](https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#binary-packages-require-build-toolchain)

Answer (score 1):

After more than 3 hours reading blog posts, I finally found a solution for me.

As 'benjamn' mentioned [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7339) ,

> many npm packages will require that you have at least gcc/g++ 4.8

When I tried:

```
gcc -v
g++ -v
```

I got 4.6

I finally updated (under Ubuntu not Windows) these (thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/312627)):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 20
```

I hope it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am building on linux, and using the above hint did:

sudo apt-get install build-essential

then

meteor add account-password

Worked!